# How do I solve this problem correctly?

Tags: functions, inequality

My acquaintance made a high school curriculum problem and asked me to solve it.
The problem is, (a and b is minimum and maximum value of $\sqrt{3}x+y$)
$$7x^{2}-6\sqrt{3}xy+13y^{2}=4$$
$$a, b \in R; a \leq \sqrt{3}x+y \leq b$$
$$a+b=?$$
and my answer is,
$$k=\sqrt{3}x+y; a \leq k \leq b$$
$$7x^{2}-6\sqrt{3}x(-\sqrt{3}x+k)+13(-\sqrt{3}x+k)^{2}=4$$
$$64x^{2}-32\sqrt{3}kx+13k^{2}-4=0$$
$$D=(32\sqrt{3}k)^{2}-4\cdot64\cdot(13k^{2}-4)
\\=4\cdot64(12k^{2}-13k^{2}+4))=256(4-k^{2})$$
$$D\geq0, \therefore k^{2} \leq 4$$
$$\therefore a=-2, b=2, a+b=0$$
He said, the answer was right, but a and b are wrong.
I think there's a problem with the solving process, but I don't know what kind of error I made.

Comment: Not following.  How are $a,b$ determined from what's given?  It looks like you can lower $a$ or raise $b$ as much as you like.

Comment: That's right. he didn't write a as max... but I have to solve it as he wants.

Comment: Instead of k in the expression for y you might take $1+k$ or some other expression.

Comment: Well,  if you somehow know what's being asked,  you should add it to the question.  Add it stands there is no answer.  Note too that there's no minimum as you can fix a good $b$ and then lower $a$ as much as you like.

Comment: k depends on x, if we ask you to solve the equation (of unknown x), you will give your solutions according to x so according to the unknown!

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Why is this solution wrong?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English so I didn't know how to ask questions on this site,,

Comment: I think the minimum and maximum of $y+x\sqrt{3}$ is sought. And it looks like they are equal and opposite.

Comment: Yes, the answer he said is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some substitutions could help. In the end a coordinate transformation essentially rotates the ellipse so its lines of symmetry are parallel to the coordinate axes, then the semi-major and semi-minor axes can be read off by letting the quadratic terms go to zero. This is allowed because having the new quadratic terms go to zero implies a straight line in the original x-y coordinates passing through the origin which necessarily intersects the ellipse somewhere.

$7x^2-6\sqrt{3}xy+13y^2=4$

$u=y+x\sqrt{3}$

$v=y-x\sqrt{3}$

$y=(u+v)/2$. $x=(u-v)/2\sqrt{3}$

$7(u-v)^2-18(u^2-v^2)+39(u+v)^2$

$7u^2+7v^2-14uv -18u^2+18v^2+39u^2+78uv+39v^2$

$28u^2+64v^2+64uv=4$

$7u^2+16v^2+16uv=1$

$3u^2+(4v)^2+4u(4v)+4u^2=1$

$3u^2+4(v+u)^2=1$

$u=\pm\sqrt{3}/3$

Comment: Can you explain how the answer comes out at the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you fix x, and solve your last equation of unknown k:

you get a condition for the existence of k: $|x|\leq \frac{\sqrt{13}}{{4}}$

and the solutions $-\frac{2}{13}\left(\sqrt{13-16x^2}-8\sqrt{3}x\right)$,

$\frac{2}{13}\left(\sqrt{13-16x^2}+8\sqrt{3}x\right)$

function studies on $[-\sqrt{13}/4,\sqrt{13}/4]$ show that:

there is a min = -2 at $x=\sqrt{3}/2$ and a max = $4\sqrt{3/13}$ at $x=\sqrt{13}/4$

and a min = $-4\sqrt{3/13}$ at $x=-\sqrt{13}/4$ and a max = 2 at $x=\sqrt{3}/2$